# About the solutions of the equation $ay^p-bx^q=k$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations

For every combination of integer numbers $a,b,k$
is it possible to find at least one solution of the equation:
$$ay^p-bx^q=k?$$
I know that in 1976 Michel Langevin proved that the problem is decidable and he showed it exists an upper bound for the values of $x$ and $y$. Has any progress been made since then?
Thanks.

Comment: Trivially possible, as long as $\gcd(a, b) \mid k$.  You may mean $p, q > 1$.

Comment: @Macavity: $(p,q)\gt 1$

Comment: It's unknown whether the equation $y^p-x^q=6$ has any solutions (or even whether it has finitely many solutions).

Comment: Even when $(a,b) = 1$ one can find congruence obstructions. There are no solutions to $y^p - 4 x^q = 2$ with $p \ge 2$.